# Customize the toolbar/actionbar in Android?

Tags: android

I have applied [MaterialNavigationDrawer component](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer) to my app for first activity.

I want to create a custom height toolbar with a background image like:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1) create a layout xml with the layout you need.(as you have shown in image). with name actionbar_custom.
2) write following code in your MainActivity.onCreate

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View actionView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);
/*here find your views inside that layout, and make runtime changes. e.g. define onTouch/onClick triggers here..    */  

actionBar.setCustomView(actionView);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try toolbar

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts.
[Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/back"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"/>
    <in.mobilepedia.com.gicgwaliarincubationcentre.util.TextViewNormal
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Document Upload"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:id="@+id/txtDocumentUpload"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/option"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/upload_white"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make a custom layout and change the layout according to the requirement and include that layout with any xml file.